# Open set in $R^2$ and $R^3$

Tags: general-topology

This might be silly question, but I have a curious about the below.

Let's consider the real number set $R$ and its usual topology, $U$

It is trivial that open interval on the line in $R$ is a openset.

Then, Does still holds in $R^2$ and $R^3$ cases ?

I.e.

First question)

Considering the $R^2$ case, $(a,b)$ or $\forall$ open interval $I$ on any line in $R^2$ (confer the below picture)
[image]

- black line means $xy$ axis and blue is a open interval on the red line

Does these are still open set in $R^2$ ?

Second, Let's expand our consideration the $R^3$ case

Then, Both of the open ball(open circle in $R^2$) and open interval are open in $R^3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the open intervals on a line are *not* open in the standard topology on the plane. This is because a subset $O$ of $\Bbb R^2$ is open iff

$$\forall x \in O: \exists r>0: B(x,r) \subseteq O$$ where $B(x,r)$ is the usual open ball in the plane: $B(x,r)  = \{(y_1,y_2): \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2} < r\}$ or equivalently say that all open sets are such balls and all possible unions of balls.

The line-intervals cannot contain any open ball (intuitively because they're just one-dimensional, and balls in the plane are two-dimensional, so they "stick out")
and so are not open.

If all such line intervals would be open, singleton sets (which can be seen as intersections of such intervals) would be open too, making the planar topology discrete and less useful.

The same goes for higher dimensions: we consider open balls of the same dimension only. Planar subsets are all nowhere dense, as lines etc. (they contain no open subsets.)